# RabbitMQ c# System.IO.EndOfStreamException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I get the following exception when a consumer is blocking to receive a message from the SharedQueue:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.EndOfStreamException: SharedQueue closed
   at RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.EnsureIsOpen()
   at RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.Dequeue()
   at Consumer.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\pdecker\Documents\Visual
Studio 2012\Projects\RabbitMQTest1\Consumer\Program.cs:line 33
```

Here is the line of code that is being executed when the exception is thrown:

```
BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
```

So far I have seen the exception occuring when rabbitMQ is inactive.  Our application needs to have the consumer always connected and listening for keystrokes.  Does anyone know the cause of this problem?  Does anyone know how to recover from this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the RMQ log say on the last line? Are you waiting for inpput in console? (default heartbeat is 5sec)

Comment: Yes, everything is running on the same laptop: RabbitMQ server, an application that is the producer, and another application that is the consumer. Here are the last lines of the log:

Comment: =INFO REPORT==== 13-Dec-2013::10:55:18 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.344.0> ([FE80::1577:7B91:63E:FD3A]:49475 -> [FE80::1577:7B91:63E:FD3A]:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 13-Dec-2013::11:06:09 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.344.0> ([FE80::1577:7B91:63E:FD3A]:49475 -> [FE80::1577:7B91:63E:FD3A]:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

Comment: Sorry, I pressed ENTER prematurely.  The keystrokes are read using the windows hook, so key presses can be entered anywhere.  The producer application and the consumer application are both c# console apps. that display the outgoing/incoming messages.

Comment: I've experienced this behaviour myself and am currently confirming cause with the RabbitMQ engineers. Do you have any kind of load balancer between your consuming application and RabbitMQ. If so, I suspect that your connection is being closed by the server because the built-in heartbeat feature is disrupted by the load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

The consumer is tied to the channel:

```
var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
```

So if the channel has closed, then the consumer will not be able to fetch any additional events once the local `Queue` has been cleared.

Check for the channel to be open with

```
channel.IsOpen == true
```

and that the Queue has available events with

```
if( consumer.Queue.Count() > 0 )
```

before calling:

```
BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
```

---

To be more specific, I would check the following before calling `Dequeue()`

```
if( !channel.IsOpen || !connection.IsOpen )
{
    Your_Connection_Channel_Init_Function();
    consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);  // consumer is tied to channel
}

if( consumer.Queue.Any() )
    BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
```

Comment: Why autorecovery doesn't do this itself?

Comment: It is better just to handle the Exception. The channel/connection states can be asked after the fact for details. In the current code channel/connection can die between the check and the dequeue and the dequeue can still throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry this is just expected behavior, it means there is no message left in queue to process. Don't even try it is not gonna work...

```
consumer.Queue.Any()
```

Just catch the EndOfStreamException:

```
private void ConsumeMessages(string queueName)
{
    using (IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (IModel channel = conn.CreateModel())
        {
            var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Waiting for messages from: {0}", queueName));

            while (true)
            {
                BasicDeliverEventArgs ea = null;
                try
                {
                    ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                }
                catch (EndOfStreamException endOfStreamException)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(endOfStreamException);
                    // If you want to end listening end of queue call break;
                    break;    
                }
                if (ea == null) break;
                var body = ea.Body;
                // Consume message how you want
                Thread.Sleep(300);
                channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible source of trouble: your corporate firewall.

Thats because such firewall can drop your connection to RabbitMQ when the connection is idle for a certain amount of time.

Although RabbitMQ connection has a [heartbeat](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)  feature to prevent this, if the heartbeat pulse happens after the firewall connection timeout, it is useless.

This is the default heartbeat interval [configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) in seconds:

> Default: 60 (580 prior to release 3.5.5)

From [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html):
***Detecting Dead TCP Connections with Heartbeats
Introduction***

> Network can fail in many ways, sometimes pretty subtle (e.g. high
>   ratio packet loss). Disrupted TCP connections take a moderately long
>   time (about 11 minutes with default configuration on Linux, for
>   example) to be detected by the operating system. AMQP 0-9-1 offers a
>   heartbeat feature to ensure that the application layer promptly finds
>   out about disrupted connections (and also completely unresponsive
>   peers). 
>   **Heartbeats also defend against certain network equipment which
>   may terminate "idle" TCP connections.**

That happened to us and we solved the problem by decreasing the Heartbeat Timeout Interval in the global configuration:

In your rabbitmq.config, find the ***heartbeat*** and set it to a value smaller than that of your firewall rule.

You can [change the interval in your client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html), too:

> Enabling Heartbeats with Java Client To configure the heartbeat
>   timeout in the Java client, set it with
>   ConnectionFactory#setRequestedHeartbeat before creating a connection:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();

// set the heartbeat timeout to 60 seconds
cf.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
```

> Enabling Heartbeats with the .NET Client To configure the heartbeat
>   timeout in the .NET client, set it with
>   ConnectionFactory.RequestedHeartbeat before creating a connection:

```
var cf = new ConnectionFactory();
//set the heartbeat timeout to 60 seconds
cf.RequestedHeartbeat = 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here that say that this is the expected behavior are correct, however I would argue that it's bad to have it throw an exception by design like this.

from [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.Dequeue): "Callers of Dequeue() will block if no items are available until some other thread calls Enqueue() or the queue is closed. In the latter case this method will throw EndOfStreamException."

So, like GlenH7 said, you have to check that channel is open before calling Dequeue() (IModel.IsOpen).

However, what if the channel closes while Dequeue() is blocking? I think it's best to call Queue.DequeueNoWait(null), and block the thread yourself by waiting for it to return something that isn't null. So, something like:

```
while(channel.IsOpen)
{
    var args = consumer.Queue.DequeueNoWait(null);
    if(args == null) continue;
    //...
}
```

This way, it won't throw that exception.

Comment: Without some other wait this code will hot-busy-loop. Nothing on the queue? Okay, let's try to look on the queue again *right away*! The exception is fine; the only real reason to use DequeueNoWait is if using another wait construct (eg. Task.Wait, Handle.Wait) not related to Rabbit.